# File properties are lost when a file is pushed inside the JMS queue in Mule 3.5

Tags: file-io, jms, mule, mule-el, mule-component

I want to use a JMS queue to store a file and process later.
I can read it from queue;I get a byte array and I can write it to a folder. But the file name is lost when I push to queue as Inbound properties are lost.

```
<file:endpoint path="C:\Store" name="storage" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
<file:file-to-byte-array-transformer doc:name="File to Byte Array"/>
<jms:outbound-endpoint doc:name="Storage Queue" connector-ref="Active_MQ" queue="file.queue"/>
```

How can I associate the original filename back again. Is there any transformer that preserves the file name before pushing in Mule?

Comment: What are you tying to do ?? .. please explain clearly .. How can you push a payload to JMS queue using <jms:inbound-endpoint ? It should be <jms:outbound-endpoint ..

Comment: You are correct,edited it. So, think I push a file called sun.pdf to a JMS.Now I will retrieve it by using an inbound JMS. What happens is I get only a byte array of file. When I write it to a folder, this file name is written as null. I want to retain the file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like the following to read from Queue and write to a file with original file name ... A simple example here where a file is read from a flow and send to JMS Queue and the next flow takes the file out of JMS queue and write to folder with original file name :-

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file"
    xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking"
    xmlns:jms="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.5.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms/current/mule-jms.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd">

    <jms:activemq-connector name="Active_MQ"
        brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Active MQ" />
    <flow name="JMSSender" doc:name="JMSSender">
        <file:inbound-endpoint responseTimeout="10000"
            doc:name="File" path="E:\backup\test">
            <file:filename-regex-filter pattern="sun.pdf,aa.txt" caseSensitive="false" />
        </file:inbound-endpoint>

        <file:file-to-byte-array-transformer /> <!-- This is necessary otherwise the output PDF file will be corrupted .. -->

        <set-session-variable variableName="FileName" value="#[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename]" doc:name="Session Variable" />

        <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="MyQueue"  connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS" exchange-pattern="request-response">
        </jms:outbound-endpoint>

    </flow>


    <flow name="JMSReceiver" doc:name="JMSReceiver">

        <jms:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="Active_MQ"
            doc:name="JMS" exchange-pattern="request-response" address="jms://tcp:MyQueue">
        </jms:inbound-endpoint>

        <file:outbound-endpoint path="E:\backup\test\ss" outputPattern="#[sessionVars['FileName']]" responseTimeout="10000"
            doc:name="File" />
    </flow>


</mule>
```

Here you can receive the original file name using session variable ...

Comment: You will get original File Name using Session variable

Answer (score 1):

Try the jms:outbound-endpoint in the following way.

```
<jms:outbound-endpoint doc:name="Storage Queue" connector-ref="Active_MQ" queue="file.queue">
          <copy-properties propertyName="*"></copy-properties>
</jms:outbound-endpoint>
```

This helps you preserve all the inbound properties when you post your payload onto a JMS queue.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi thanks for reply,so I do use this thing.Can you plz tell how I associate this property to the byte array I get from Queue

Comment: Its the same way you accessed the filename in the first(file inbound) flow #[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename]   In the JMS Inbound flow also you can access the Filename Property same way.

Comment: Actually when this Jms-outbound changes to Jms-inbound we loose the value from inbound properties.It is set to null.

Comment: That is why we are using copyProperties tag inside the JMS Outbound. This tag copies all the inboundproperties to outbound properties. Then in the receiving flow (JMS INbound) these properties come out as inbound properties.

Comment: hmm doesn't look like that.Actually I wanted to achieve this using your method but didn't work so going for session-vars.